# Authentication tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: salesforcedx

I execute these tasks:

1. `sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a DevHub`
2. a web page was opened login.salesforce.com, I am connected
3. I am redirected to localhost :1717 (not accessible)
4. in the command line I have this error : ***ERROR running force:auth:web:login:  tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT*** xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:8080

I dont have a proxy:

```
D:\USERS\xxxxxx\sfprojects>netsh winhttp show proxy

Paramètres de proxy WinHTTP actuels :

    Accès direct (sans serveur proxy).
```

Why do I get a timedout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem. There is no proxy in the network entreprise but under Windows there is HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables registred, I have removed them and restarted my machin and finally the command works now.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy might be configured in `npm` (used by `sfdc` CLI) or you might have a network element that is not a proxy blocking access. You can try removing proxy config from npm and see if that helps:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```